# Объединить 2 запроса с подсчётом найденных соответствий

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Есть 3 таблицы:

1. **properties** объекты `id | published | ...`
2. **categories** категории объектов `id | category_name | ...`
3. **property_categories** связь объектов с категориями (один объект может принадлежать к нескольким категориям) `... | pid | category_id |`

Нужно получить многомерный массив категорий объектов с кол-вом объектов, входящих в данную категорию, исключая 0. На данный момент одним запросом я получаю массив категорий, а уже перебирая массив делаю подсчёт кол-ва соответствий в таблице объектов. Для упрощения я удалил из кода всё лишнее:

***Вытаскиваю категории, которые используются, то есть если их `id` встречается в объектах и они опубликованы:***

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.category_name
FROM categories AS a
INNER JOIN property_categories AS b ON a.id = b.category_id
INNER JOIN properties AS c ON b.pid = c.id AND c.published = '1'
```

Можно ли (нужно ли) обойтись без `DISTINCT`, избегая повторений в полученном массиве?

***Разбираю массив и считаю кол-во объектов категории в цикле:***

```
for($i=0;$i<count($categories);$i++){
$category = $categories[$i];
...
    SELECT COUNT(a.id)
    FROM properties AS a
    INNER JOIN property_categories AS b ON b.pid = a.id
    INNER JOIN categories AS c ON b.category_id = c.id AND c.id = '$category->id'
    WHERE a.published = 1
...
}
```

**Как можно получить кол-во объектов категории в первом же запросе, избежав последующие запросы в цикле?**

Кажется, что истина уже где-то рядом, но голова уже кругом =(

Comment: `select a.id, a.category_name, count(1) from ... where .... group by a.id, a.category_name`

Comment: @Mike спасибо большущее, это работает!

Comment: @Mile никак не пойму, в `count(1)` единица означает номер столбца по которому идёт подсчёт? Как это работает?

Comment: А не нужно считать конкретную колонку. count(колонка) считает not null значения в ней. count(1) считает просто кол-во строк, т.к. в каждой встреченной строке видит 1. Почитайте еще вот это http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511270/mysql-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5/511297#511297   тут недавно как раз были проблемы с производительностью из за count(колонка)

Comment: В принципе стандарты SQL для таких случаев рекомендуют count(*), но я его не люблю, в старом оракле оптимизатор лучше работал с count(1) чем со *

Comment: @Mike я перечитал документацию и везде встречал только варианты со *, по-этому и стало интересно, как это работает. Я перечитал ваш ответ по представленной ссылке и более менее стало понятно, спасибо! Но ещё  более интересно - я заметил, что `count(12876423146)` будет работать точно также, как и `count(1)`, по-этому и встал вопрос - что же всё-таки означает эта единица?))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ответ из комментариев от [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)*

```
SELECT
  a.id AS id,
  a.category_name AS category_name,
  count(1) AS total
FROM
  categories AS a
INNER JOIN
  property_categories AS b
ON
  a.id = b.category_id
INNER JOIN
  properties AS c
ON
  b.pid = c.id
WHERE
  c.published = '1'
GROUP BY
  a.id, a.category_name
```